# Moving images to another folder Powershell

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am trying to move images from one folder to another. The images folder contains like 1000 images. i want to move the first 100 images to one folder the other 100 images to another folder and the other 100 images to another folder.
i found a script that moves all the images. but i need to move by 100.
even if i get the code for first 100 i can change the path in the code(target Path).
Thanks

```
$sourcePath = "/sitecore/media library/Default Website" 
$targetPath = "/sitecore/media library/dev" 
$optionalTemplateNameToMatch = "" 
# optional template get children line 
# Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.TemplateName -match $optionalTemplateNameToMatch } | ForEach-Object {    
 
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {  
    $name = $_.Name 
    if(![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($name)) 
    { 
        Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $targetPath; 
        Write-Host "Item moved to: "$_.ItemPath; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Couldn’t move Item because empty name: " $_.Id; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using item buckets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy to update the target path each time, then all you need to do is add a counter into your script, then check its less than 100 each time through the for loop.

```
$sourcePath = "/sitecore/media library/Default Website" 
$targetPath = "/sitecore/media library/dev" 
$counter = 0 
 
Get-ChildItem $sourcePath -Recurse | ForEach-Object {  

    $name = $_.Name 
    if((![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($name)) -and ($counter -lt 100) -and ($_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder))) 
    { 
        Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $targetPath; 
        Write-Host "Item moved to: "$_.ItemPath; 
        $counter+=1
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Couldn’t move Item because empty name: " $_.Id; 
    } 
}
```

Note I also added in a check to confirm the templateId for the item is not a folder.

When testing out powershell scripts in sitecore, it is useful to first do a test run to see what would be effected without moving the items themselves.

The script below, splits the actions into two methods Find-MediaItems and Move-MediaItems. You can then call Find-MediaItems first and output the results to table.

If you are happy with what is going to be moved, you then need to uncomment the line #MoveItem($item), and comment out the line above.

```
function Find-MediaItems {
    $items = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath.Paths.FullPath | 
    Where-Object { ($_.TemplateID -ne [Sitecore.TemplateIDs]::MediaFolder) }
        
    foreach($item in $items) {
        $item;
        #MoveItem($item)
    }
}

function MoveItem($item)
{
    $name=$item.Name
    if((![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($name)) -and ($counter -lt 100))) 
    { 
        Move-Item -Path $_.ItemPath -Destination $targetPath; 
        Write-Host "Item moved to: "$_.ItemPath; 
        $counter+=1
    } 
    else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Couldn’t move Item because empty name: " $_.Id; 
    } 
}

$props = @{
    InfoTitle = "Media items to move"
    InfoDescription = "Lists all media items that the script will eventually move"
    PageSize = 25
}

Find-MediaItems |
    Show-ListView @props -Property @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName} },
        @{Label="Updated"; Expression={$_.__Updated} },
        @{Label="Updated by"; Expression={$_."__Updated by"} },
        @{Label="Created"; Expression={$_.__Created} },
        @{Label="Created by"; Expression={$_."__Created by"} },
        @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.ItemPath} }
        
Close-Window
```

The above is something I found myself when in similar situation to you, then have edited to suit over time (cant recall original source).